# generate a tree in scala

Tags: scala, data-structures, tree

I am learning Scala and the book that I am using provides an exercise that asks me to define some functions on a tree structure.

The tree is defined as:

```
sealed trait Tree[+A]
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
```

One of the exercise is to count the number of nodes in the tree. 
I wrote the function but I can not check if it is working because I do not have any example of tree.

How can I generate a small tree that I can use to test my code?

It is probably possible to add one element at the time to the tree but it seems like a lot of work.

Comment: Well, unless you create a method to handle creating a tree and adding nodes to it, you are going to have to do it by hand. A simple insert to a tree is not very complex and a pretty good excercise in itself :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just something like

```
val tree = Branch(
             Branch(
               Leaf(12),
               Branch(
                 Leaf(3),
                 Leaf(4))),
             Leaf(8))
```

That should be the tree

> ```
>       *
>     /   \
>    *     8
>   /  \
>  12   *
>      /  \
>      3   4
> ```

You can reuse that in a bigger tree. The point is that you build bottom up, you cannot at something at the bottom, that requires creating a new tree from scratch

```
val biggerTree = Branch(Branch(something, tree), stillSomethingElse)
```

---

In complement of @dhg's answer, a variant which generates a tree with a given number of branches (note: there are always one more leaves than there are branches, so the total number branches + leaves is always odd). That should make testing straightforward

```
def randomTree(branchCount: Int): Tree[Int] =
  if(branchCount == 0) Leaf(0) // whatever, you can put a random here
  else {
     val branchCountAtLeft = util.Random.nextInt(branchCount) 
          // between 0 and branchCount - 1
     val branchCountAtRight = branchCount - 1 - branchCountAtLeft
     Branch(randomTree(branchCountAtLeft), randomTree(branchCountAtRight))
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

@Didier's answer is good for making your own trees by hand, but if you want to **automatically** generate trees, you can do so with a little recursive generator:

```
def generate(p: Double): Tree[Int] = {
  if (util.Random.nextDouble < p)
    Branch(generate(p), generate(p))
  else
    Leaf(0)
}
```

Then you just do:

```
val t = generate(0.5)
println(t)
```

and you'll get a random tree.  Lowering `p` will make the trees tend smaller; raising it will make them tend bigger.

Clearly this will make trees with all leafs the same value.  If you want random leaf values, try:

```
 Leaf(util.Random.nextInt(100))
```

Comment: It is possible that the right version should have `Branch(generate(p), generate(p))`?

Comment: @Donbeo, oops, yep, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also move the code of `generate` method written by @dgh to `apply` method of Tree comppanion object

```
package datastructures

sealed trait Tree[+A]

case class Leaf[A](value :A) extends Tree[A]
case class Branch[A](left:Tree[A],right:Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]

  object Tree{
    def apply(p: Double): Tree[Int] = {
      if (util.Random.nextDouble < p)
        Branch(apply(p), apply(p))
      else
        Leaf(util.Random.nextInt(100))        }
  }
```

and then use it like

```
val t = Tree(0.5)
println(t)
```